# Projective Plane Curves - W. Fulton 5.15

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

**PRLOBEM:** I need to show that if C be an irreducible projective plane curve $C$, $P_1,\ldots , P_n$ simple
points on $C$, $m_1,\ldots , m_n$ integers, then there is a $z \in k(C)$ with $\text{ord}_{P_i}(z) = m_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

I already have the following fact:

**FACT:** If $P_1,\ldots , P_n \in \mathbb{P}^2$, there are an infinite number of line
passing through $P_1$, but ont through $P_2,\ldots , P_n$. If $P_1$ is a simple point on $F$, we may take these lines transversal to $F$ at $P_1$.

The idea is to consider the same lines $L_i$ as in fact for $P_i$, and a line $L_0$ not through any $P_j$, and let $z = \prod L_i^{m_i}L_0^{-\Sigma m_i}$.

I've tried to develop from there, but I couldn't. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly. If I could I wouldn't have posted it here. That's why I asked for help. If you want to help, since you know, thank you!

Comment: No, I mean, if you're looking for help, you need to explain what *specifically* you need help with - which part of considering $z$ as an element of the local ring and computing it's valuation do you need help with? And asking for help while simultaneously downvoting one of my posts (I didn't even vote on your post so far!) is unlikely to get a good response. Good luck.

Comment: When I said I was having trouble, it was calculating the z rating. It's really something I struggle with. Also, at no time did I downvote any of your posts, maybe it was someone else. But it's alright!